# Laravel, variable output work with View::share but not with VIew::composer

Tags: view, laravel, laravel-4, twig

I need the same menu in all my views.

So I get data I need for output the menu in a constructor defined in my BaseController.

To got the data I've first tried to use View::composer but dunno why I doesn't get any error, it looks like View::composer isn't executed at all...

If I use View::share, its work

//BaseController.php

```
//function called in the constructor
public function init()
{
    $envs = $this->game->environments()->get();

    View::share('test', $envs);

    View::composer('layouts.base', function($view)
    {
        $view->with('envs', $envs);
    });
}
```

//base.twig

```
//nothing output here, no error
{% for env in envs %}
         {{ env.name }}
{% endfor %}

//its work
{% for env in test %}
         {{ env.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm new to laravel so maybe I miss something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason that this isn't working is because of where you put the View Composer in your code. View Composers in Laravel are essentially callbacks that are executed as soon as the view is rendered. Where is this `init()` function defined? My guess is that the view is being created *before* your view composer is defined - meaning that the view composer callback will never be executed.

Try moving the whole view composer block from the `init()` function and append it to the bottom of your routes.php file and see if it works. That's not a bad spot to place your view composers if you do not have too many, if you do you could create a new class to store them in and add that path to your autoload path.

Read more about view composers [here](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers)

Comment: I write my View composer based on your link already, it said anything about the fact we have to put them in a special spot. :/

It mean views are rendered before the BaseController constructor ? A bit strange !

Thanks for your answer, I will use class to store them.

I just want to know one thing, in my example I should use a View composer or keep using View share ? I already seen topics about that but doesn't answer really since View share are kind of global for all views, my view composer on the base template should do the same since all my templates extends the base.twig template ?

Comment: I don't think views are _rendered_ before the BaseController - they are _created_ before, and the view composer callback fires only upon **creation** of a new view...so the call the view composer in your original code will never fire because they view has been created already.

As for view share VS composer - I would use composers if you need to do something in the callback to alter the variables that you are passing to the view. If you are simply passing a non-dynamic variable to the view my recommendation would be to use view shares.